# Does burning plastic completely disintegrate it? Accidentally melted some plastic in a BBQ, wondering if pyrolytic cleaning is an option

Tags: everyday-chemistry, cleaning

I accidentally barbecued some plastic today, making quite a mess. It's a cushion for a lawn chair, so I imagine probably some sort of plastic or polyurethane.

Rather than cleaning melted plastic manually, I'm wondering if its a good idea to just burn it off? The BBQ is a Kamado oven, so it can reach about $\pu{350 ^\circ C}$ or $\pu{700 ^\circ F}$ for a sustained period of time.

It's a well ventilated area, so smoke isn't a concern. I am somewhat concerned that it may not burn completely and contaminate future cooks.

Can anybody offer some insights on if $\pu{350 ^\circ C}$ is hot enough or if this is a good idea at all?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you barbecued a lawn chair cushion?

Comment: Well, the tags are appropriate. If it was me, I would replace the affected part: even scraping, sanding and heating it for a few hours would not erase the memory of what happened and who last sat on the BBQ’ed cushion.

Comment: @EdV is right. As an experienced grillsman living in Texas, I can assure you that you don't want to season your rig improperly, and that precludes using plastic and law furniture components for that task. Nor should you diminish the BBQ experience for your guests by offering charred lawn furniture on which to sit: that's impolite. You wouldn't skip on the marinade, or the sides and the ice-cold beer: do the right thing and respect the entire experience.

Comment: I would imagine that burning the plastic would work, but I would probably not recommend this method because it will likely release a ton of toxic smoke. I cannot post this as an answer because I don't feel certain enough on the "burning would work" part.

Comment: Reducing everithing to soot than chair than clean as usual seems a good idea, especially if the plastic is in the "furnace" Not really a question for Chemistry SE but worth a comment.

Comment: Heh, I did in fact bbq a lawn chair cushion. What can I say, always check the inside before you light a bbq.

Comment: @user1543574 Sounds like you might need to contact [Kamodo Joe support](https://www.kamadojoe.com/pages/support) folks. Good luck and keep on grillin'!